# How to observe a TextField value with SwiftUI and Combine?

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to execute an action every time a `textField`'s value is changed.

```
@Published var value: String = ""

var body: some View {            
     $value.sink { (val) in
        print(val)
     }
     return TextField($value)       
}
```

But I get below error.

> Cannot convert value of type 'Published' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should be a non-fragile way of doing it:

```
class MyData: ObservableObject {
    var value: String = "" {
        willSet(newValue) {
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = MyData()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input:", text: $data.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your code, `$value` is a publisher, while `TextField` requires a binding. While you can change from `@Published` to `@State` or even `@Binding`, that can't observe the event when the value is changed.

It seems like there is no way to observe a binding.

An alternative is to use `ObservableObject` to wrap your value type, then observe the publisher (`$value`).

```
class MyValue: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: String = ""
  init() {
    $value.sink { ... }
  }
}
```

Then in your view, you have have the binding `$viewModel.value`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyValue()
    var body: some View {
        TextField($viewModel.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a caveat. The `sink` is emitted before the value is changed. If you need the value after it is updated, refer to https://samwize.com/2020/06/03/subscribing-to-published/.

Answer (score 6):

I don't use combine for this. This it's working for me:

```
 TextField("write your answer here...",
            text: Binding(
                     get: {
                        return self.query
                       },
                     set: { (newValue) in
                        self.fetch(query: newValue) // any action you need
                                return self.query = newValue
                      }
            )
  )
```

I have to say it's not my idea, I read it in this blog: [SwiftUI binding: A very simple trick](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-binding-a-very-simple-trick-c975a1abbf9c)

Comment: Not the best option to use, Combine makes it easier.

Comment: @evya, could you explain how? I'd prefer to use Combine!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to observe `value` then it should be a `State`

```
@State var value: String = ""
```

Comment: I also tried to use didSet for a State var, but it did not work

Comment: why are you trying dot set Did set? remove `$value.sink { (val) in print(val) }` and leave just a print and it will work

Comment: $value contains the whole textfield value, while ```$value.publisher().sink { }``` let you do something at each keystroke. Check my posted answered.

Comment: Not working for me as I think `$value.publisher().sink { }` is deprecated in Beta 6. Do you have any other solution how to observe TextField value

Comment: @Evana it's still there just call `value.publisher.sink { }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe `TextField` value by using ways,

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
     
    @State private var Text1 = ""
    @State private var Text2 = ""
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ObserveTextFieldValue()
    
    var body: some View {
        
            //MARK: TextField with Closures
              TextField("Enter text1", text: $Text1){
                  editing in
                  print(editing)
              }onCommit: {
                  print("Committed")
              }
        
            //MARK: .onChange Modifier
              TextField("Enter text2", text: $Text2).onChange(of: Text2){
                  text in
                     print(text)
              }
    
            //MARK: ViewModel & Publisher(Combine)
              TextField("Enter text3", text: $viewModel.value)
    }
}



class ObserveTextFieldValue: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: String = ""
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  init() {
      $value.sink(receiveValue: {
          val in
          print(val)
      }).store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

Comment: StateObject is for initializing ObservableObjects. ObservedObjext is for observing already existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

@Published is one of the most useful property wrappers in SwiftUI, allowing us to create observable objects that automatically announce when changes occur that means whenever an object with a property marked @Published is changed, all views using that object will be reloaded to reflect those changes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var textfieldData = TextfieldData()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input:", text: $textfieldData.data)
    }
}

class TextfieldData: ObservableObject{
   @Published var data: String = ""
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: StateObject is for initializing ObservableObjects. ObservedObjext is for observing already existing ones.