# How to use Combine on a SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This question relates to this one: [How to observe a TextField value with SwiftUI and Combine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735382/how-to-observe-a-textfield-value-with-swiftui-and-combine)

But what I am asking is a bit more general. 
Here is my code:

```
struct MyPropertyStruct {
    var text: String
}

class TestModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var myproperty = MyPropertyStruct(text: "initialText")

    func saveTextToFile(text: String) {
        print("this function saves text to file")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testModel = TestModel()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $testModel.myproperty.text)
    }
}
```

**Scenario:** As the user types into the textfield, the *saveTextToFile* function should be called. Since this is saving to a file, it should be slowed-down/throttled.

**So My question is:**

1. Where is the proper place to put the combine operations in the code below.
2. What Combine code do I put to accomplish: **(A)** The string must not contain spaces. **(B)** The string must be 5 characters long. **(C)** The String must be debounced/slown down

I wanted to use the response here to be a general pattern of: *How should we handle combine stuff in a SwiftUI app (not UIKit app).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do what you want in your `ViewModel`. Your view model is the `TestModel` class (which I suggest you rename it in `TestViewModel`). It's where you are supposed to put the logic between the model and the view. The `ViewModel` should prepare the model to be ready for the visualization. And that is the right place to put your combine logic (if it's related to the view, of course).

Now we can use your specific example to actually make an example. To be honest there are a couple of slight different solutions depending on what you **really** want to achieve. But for now I'll try to be as generic as possible and then you can tell me if the solution is fine or it needs some refinements:

```
struct MyPropertyStruct {
    var text: String
}

class TestViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var myproperty = MyPropertyStruct(text: "initialText")
    private var canc: AnyCancellable!

    init() {
        canc = $myproperty.debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).sink { [unowned self] newText in
            let strToSave = self.cleanText(text: newText.text)
            if strToSave != newText.text {
                //a cleaning has actually happened, so we must change our text to reflect the cleaning
                self.myproperty.text = strToSave
            }
            self.saveTextToFile(text: strToSave)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        canc.cancel()
    }

    private func cleanText(text: String) -> String {
        //remove all the spaces
        let resultStr = String(text.unicodeScalars.filter {
            $0 != " "
        })

        //take up to 5 characters
        return String(resultStr.prefix(5))
    }

    private func saveTextToFile(text: String) {
        print("text saved")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testModel = TestViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $testModel.myproperty.text)
    }
}
```

You should attach your own `subscriber` to the `TextField` `publisher` and use the `debounce` publisher to delay the cleaning of the string and the calling to the saving method. According to the documentation:

> debounce(for:scheduler:options:)
>
> Use this operator when you want to wait for a pause in the delivery of
>   events from the upstream publisher. For example, **call debounce on the**
>   **publisher from a text field to only receive elements when the user
>   pauses or stops typing**. When they start typing again, the debounce
>   holds event delivery until the next pause.

When the user stops typing the debounce publisher waits for the specified time (in my example here above 0.5 secs) and then it calls its subscriber with the new value.

The solution above delays **both** the saving of the string **and** the `TextField` update. This means that users will see the original string (the one with spaces and maybe longer than 5 characters) for a while, before the update happens. And that's why, at the beginning of this answer, I said that there were a couple of different solutions depending on the needs. If, indeed, we want to delay just the saving of the string, but we want the users to be forbidden to input space characters or string longer that 5 characters, we can use two subscribers (I'll post just the code that changes, i.e. the `TestViewModel` class):

```
class TestViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var myproperty = MyPropertyStruct(text: "initialText")
    private var saveCanc: AnyCancellable!
    private var updateCanc: AnyCancellable!

    init() {
        saveCanc = $myproperty.debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { [unowned self] in self.cleanText(text: $0.text) }
            .sink { [unowned self] newText in
            self.saveTextToFile(text: self.cleanText(text: newText))
        }

        updateCanc = $myproperty.sink { [unowned self] newText in
            let strToSave = self.cleanText(text: newText.text)
            if strToSave != newText.text {
                //a cleaning has actually happened, so we must change our text to reflect the cleaning
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myproperty.text = strToSave
                }
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        saveCanc.cancel()
        updateCanc.cancel()
    }

    private func cleanText(text: String) -> String {
        //remove all the spaces
        let resultStr = String(text.unicodeScalars.filter {
            $0 != " "
        })

        //take up to 5 characters
        return String(resultStr.prefix(5))
    }

    private func saveTextToFile(text: String) {
        print("text saved: \(text)")
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like the code have some issues when i run it. Sometimes after the 0.5 seconds, my text in the textfield gets removed. But this is a good starting point, let me try what you have provided and see if i can improve it. If i crack it i'll return to mark this as correct.

Comment: Hi @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com are you trying the code on the simulator or on the preview? Because I can't reproduce the bug in the actual simulator.

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com also, be sure to copy-paste the current version of the code, I made several edits.

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com ah ok, no worries xD I was starting to think about some bugs on MacOS not present in the iPhone simulator.