# How to use .onSubmit() with vertical TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have a vertically growing `TextField` in `SwiftUI but also have the software keyboard have a custom submission method.

This uses the new functionality of iOS 16's `TextFields` being able to take an axis as an argument for which way it should grow. See the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:axis:)-8rujz.

Here's a sample `ContentView` showing the setup.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var message: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Try to submit this using the blue send button on the software keyboard")
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $message, axis: .vertical)
                .onSubmit {
                    print("submission!")
                }
            .submitLabel(.send)
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this, you can see the `TextField` properly grows vertically, but even when you have a custom submission label, pressing the blue "send" button in the software keyboard on iOS just inserts a newline, rather than firing the `.onSubmit`

When using a hardware keyboard, pressing the return does run the code in `.onSubmit`, so this seemingly just a limitation of the software keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Consider using *UITextView* representable [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639072/20410653). Solution below may not work in all scenarios.

I **modified [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636934/20410653) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070102/20410653)**, because in my case they led to *TextField's* jumping back and forth, adding and instantly removing a new line after hitting return (or done). If you experience similar behaviour, I combined previous solutions with [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59599928/20410653), and it helped. So, basically, you need to find out whether "\n" was inserted somewhere, and switch *FocusState* before *message* itself changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var message: String = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Placeholder",
                      text: Binding(
                        get: { message },
                        set:
                            { (newValue, _) in
                                if let _ = newValue.lastIndex(of: "\n") {
                                    isFocused = false
                                } else {
                                    message = newValue
                                }
                            }
                      ), axis: .vertical)
                .submitLabel(.done)
                .focused($isFocused)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've applied the excellent advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847538/swiftui-created-a-multiline-textfield-using-axis-vertical-and-onsubmit-wont) to your question. Would this work for you?

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var message: String = ""
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("Try to submit this using the blue send button on the software keyboard")
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $message, axis: .vertical)
            .submitLabel(.send)
            .onChange(of: message) { newValue in
                guard let newValueLastChar = newValue.last else { return }
                if newValueLastChar == "\n" {
                    message.removeLast()
                    print("submission!")
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                }
            }
                            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whoa that's creative!!

Answer (score 1):

[ej5607's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636934/555807) won't work if the user is editing partway through the string and hits the Send button. I've modified it to fix that and also use the @FocusState rather than calling in to UIApplication.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var message: String = ""
    enum Field: Int, Hashable {
        case message
    }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("Try to submit this using the blue send button on the software keyboard")
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $message, axis: .vertical)
                .submitLabel(.send)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .message)
                .onChange(of: message) { newValue in
                    if let newLineIndex = message.lastIndex(of: "\n") {
                        message.remove(at: newLineIndex)
                        print("submission!")
                        focusedField = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```